# Wordpress: Previous & Next not working in category.php

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories

My Archive.php page is working correctly, forward and backward links at the bottom work:
http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/williamsmurrayhamm/2013/01/

I duplicated this and named it category.php but the previous and next nav isn't working in my /projects/ category. I think it is something to do with the urls not being found because there is a "sub section" in the url:
http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/williamsmurrayhamm/projects/

I have custom permalink structure:
/%category%/%postname%/

Here is my loop code on both pages:

```
            <!-- main editable content grab from wordpress pages -->
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
        <br class="c" />
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore">Read More</a>
        <br class="c" />
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <?php previous_posts_link( '« Newer Entries' ) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright">
    <?php next_posts_link('Older Entries »', 0); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br class="c" />
```

Please help I have been stuck on this a few hours now.
Thanks, Archie.

Comment: Can anyone give me a quick pointer on this one please? Thanks

Comment: Please! Got a new freelance job, my biggest ever, need to impress the client!

Comment: Still can't work it out, hoping someone will answer soon, if I find the answer I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering my question (not).

Anyway I have found a plugin that fixes the error on custom category.php pagination. So here it is my fellow friends:

http://www.htmlremix.com/projects/category-pagination-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 1):

This pagination problem solved by changing 'Blog pages show at most' to 1 instead of default 10. This setting can be found in Admin > Settings > Reading.
However, this might not be the most optimum solution.